# Groovy assert: xml nodes to compare

Tags: xml, groovy, nodelist

i have an xml:

```
<body>
    <car>
        <color>green</color>
        <nr>88</nr>
    </car>
    <car>
        <color>yellow</color>
        <nr>54</nr>
    </car>
    <car>
        <color>blue</color>
        <nr>89</nr>
    </car>
    <car>
        <color>red</color>
        <nr>17</nr>
    </car>
    <car>
        <color>white</color>
        <nr>64</nr>
    </car>
</body>
```

I want to make sure that the colors are white, green, blue, yellow, red (the order doesn't matter).
So i wrote a script:

```
import groovy.util.XmlSlurper

def pXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText('<body><car><color>green</color><nr>88</nr></car><car><color>yellow</color><nr>54</nr></car><car><color>blue</color><nr>89</nr></car><car><color>red</color><nr>17</nr></car><car><color>white</color><nr>64</nr></car></body>')
def actual = pXml.car.color.sort(true) {it.text()}
def expected = ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'white', 'yellow'].sort()
assert expected==actual
```

Forgive me if it looks weird, i'm new in programming.
I tired it in online groovy parser and in SoapUI, but i always get:

```
Caught: Assertion failed: 

assert expected==actual
       |       | |
       |       | [blue, green, red, white, yellow]
       |       false
       [blue, green, red, white, yellow]
Assertion failed: 

assert expected==actual
       |       | |
       |       | [blue, green, red, white, yellow]
       |       false
       [blue, green, red, white, yellow]

at main.run(main.groovy:6)
```

Kindly advice

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Set instead of sorting

```
def actual = pXml.car.color*.text() as Set
Set expected = ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'white', 'yellow']
assert expected==actual
```

Your problem BTW was here:

```
def actual = pXml.car.color.sort(true) {it.text()}
```

That was taking all the nodes, and sorting them by their text.

It was not returning a list of Strings, it was returning a list of Nodes.

If you want to keep using Lists, you can change this to:

```
def actual = pXml.car.color*.text().sort(true)
```

To sort the String text, instead of the Nodes

Comment: Thank you!!!
Your solution with sets works in SoapUI 5.6.1, though it hangs up in online compilers like https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_groovy_online.php.


Also "def actual = pXml.car.color*.text().sort(true)" fails in SoapUI 5.6.1 with an error:
assert expectedProducts==actualProducts | | | | | [[green], [yellow], [blue], [red], [white]] | false ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'white', 'yellow'].

Comment: Though "def actualProducts = pXml.car.color.collect{it.text()}.sort(true)" works fine in SoapUI 5.6.1